# How to scrape the number of followers from a URL

Tags: python, database, excel, web-scraping, social-media

I have a list of artists in an excel file with the urls of all their social medias accounts (Facebook, Instagram, Soundcloud, Twitter and Youtube).Is there any fast way to **scrape** the number of followers for each account and report it in the excel file? I have more than 2000 artists so it will be very helpful if I could automate the task.. Thank you for your responses :)

Comment: Hey you need to try your own first show us your code and than we will help

Comment: **What have you tried?**

Comment: Scrap or Scrape?  Big difference on what you want to do with those numbers 8)

Comment: @NikhilParmar  I'm not a real coder my self, I never used Python before so I was searching for a quick answer here. But  you're right I should have tried something before asking, it's always more productive. i'll get back to you guys when I'm stucked. Thx :)

Comment: @malik that's d spirit

Comment: @AnkurGupta Nothing for the moment, i'll go with the solution of Jack first and try to write a little spider in python if it doesn't work, even though i'm a real newbie.

Comment: @ForwardEd I guess I meant "scrape". I just want to collect the data. Sorry for the poor english :)

Answer (score 0):

If

1. You don't have previous expriences in making a spider.
2. Some of these sites required login for viewing those number.
3. You only have to do this for one-time.

You may checkout [selenium-python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage), a youtube [video](https://youtu.be/--vqRAkcWoM?list=PL4tmZ2wr68XWgqJFzwWrw-JFd_vBEonsT)

It's

1. Intuitive. you can see how your program run, it controls a real browser.
2. Easy to handle captcha. you can just pause the program and type the captcha your self.

Downside:

1. Slow. It just fired up a real browser.

Comment: Thank you @jack. Indeed I have no previous experience so i'll try this out and let you know. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: There's a lot of tutorials out there. Things will be pretty straight forward, since you are actually controlling a browser. But please make sure that performance doesn't matter, (e.g. you do not need to scrap in realtime), selenium is mainly for automated testing rather than scraping.